# How to create a derivative function?

Tags: r

I was trying to create a function to derive an expression and the command gives the error below.
Can anybody help me ?

```
derivada<- function(x){

  expression(x)

  z <- D(x,"x")

  print(z)
  
} 

derivada(x^2)

Error in D(x, "x") : object 'x' not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```r
derivada <- function(x) D(substitute(x), "x")
derivada(x^2)
## 2 * x
```

- the main point here is that `substitute(x)` captures the expression that was passed as an argument **without attempting to evaluate it**. (Dealing with expressions and controlling when they get evaluated is tricky.)
- I had the function return an expression (which then gets auto-printed) rather than printing the result
- I didn't use curly brackets because the function only takes one expression (although arguably using curly brackets anyway would be better practice)